# Is it bad to make 302 and then 301 on login page

Tags: http, redirect, seo, http-status-code-301

I have code that redirects visitor to login -page via authentication provider selector -page

```
site.com/ -> 302 
site.com/check-authentication-providers.aspx -> 301 
site.com/login.aspx
```

Positive thing of course is to have code separated clearly by having separate pages but are there negative impacts on this model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Alhouth I have seen Matt Cutts (Google) state they follow more then one [redirect], each hop including the first leaks juice, he also stated they do not keep following but did not give a number. Bing states one.

Source: http://www.seomoz.org/q/how-many-jumps-between-301-redirects-is-acceptable